# Acceder a atributo de clase en la asignación de parámetros de un método

Tags: python

Verán lo que intento es crear un método donde el usuario pueda o no asignar parámetros, ya que en caso de no asignarlos el método tomara por default los asignados en el constructor, el problema es que no me deja asignar los parámetros por default ya que `self` no esta declarado en ese ámbito (lo cual tiene sentido), simplificando la idea es la siguiente.

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def metodo(self, n=self.n):   #Aqui es el error
        return n
```

lo que se me ocurre por hacer es lo siguiente

```
def metodo(self, n=None):
    n = n if n else self.n
    return n
```

pero no se si sea la mejor manera, ya que tengo varios métodos en los que pensaba aplicar eso, habrá una manera de hacerlo como en el primer ejemplo?, o tengo que hacerlo como en el segundo?.

gracias

Comment: Podrías revisar el código de tu pregunta, la indentación no es correcta lo que puede llevar a malentendidos.

Comment: es verdad, no me di cuenta, ya esta corregido gracias

Comment: El título dice "atributo de clase", pero `self.n` sería un atributo de objeto, y no de clase. ¿Está bien lo de `self` o realmente necesitas que sea un atributo de clase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que en `python` el valor de `self.n` se define en tiempo de ejecución la forma correcta es parecida a la segunda, aunque como menciona la otra respuesta, el `if n` podría retornar `False` en varios casos además de `None`, si `n` es `0` o `''`, por ejemplo. Por lo que la versión correcta debe ser explicitamente preguntar `if n is None`:

```
def metodo(n=None):
    n = self.n if n is None else n
    return n
```

En el caso de que ambos tengan contenido se queda con el primero, y cuando es `None` con el segundo.

Sin embargo, debo notar que algo no esta OK con tu código y es que los métodos de una clase requieren una referencia a si mismos (`self`), por lo que se podría solucionar tu problema accediendo directamente al atributo desde la referencia a `self`.

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def metodo(self, n=None):
        n = self.n if n is None else n
        return n
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se quiere establecer un valor por defecto de un argumento de un método dependa de algun atributo de la clase lo correcto es usar None como intentas pero hay que dar mejoras:

- El primer argumento de un método es siempre `self`, salvo que sea un método estático.
- `if n` no es la manera correcta de validar si un objeto es None o no, ya que por ejemplo si `n = None` o `n = False` o `n = ""` se obtiene el mismo resultado, lo correcto es usar `if n is None`

En conclusion la solución es:

```py
class Clase:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def metodo(n = None):
        return self.n if n is None else n
```